"Which salon hair did you get this haircut from?" Does it sound natural?

Which salon hair did you get this haircut from?

Please can you help me. Is there any mistake in the sentence? Please explain why.

Requests to spot mistakes are off-topic.

@SeowjoohengSingapore Yeah, it's not completely on topic, but it's still answerable (as I did just now).

another way is which salon did your hair? ... might be something other than a haircut

There is a mistake in your sentence: there's no such thing as a "salon hair", only a "hair salon" (salon is not a hair style. Even if it's "bowl cut" instead, "bowl cut hair" is still somewhat weird). Thus, to correct:

Which hair salon did you get this haircut from?

To make this more fluent and native (but less formal and reduced information),

Where did you get this haircut?

Both are good and correct. The first is essentially a corrected version of your sentence, and retains all the information. The second omits the "hair salon" part, since "where" in this case implies that you went to a hair salon. The second version also removes the "from", as "where did you get" already conveys the meaning, and "from" is a bit redundant.

I've heard the term salon hair ... I think that it refers to hair that has been damaged by too many visits to the hair salon

@jsotola Yeah, quite a funny definition. But I don't think that's an official term, probably some recently invented internet slang. Al least I can't find it in the dictionary. If you thinks there's actually an official English phrase that is "salon hair", please provide a link to a reputable source so I can check out myself.

In America, if you simply say "salon" it is understood to mean a hair salon. If you mean some other kind of salon, you have to specify. Like you can say, "I went to a tanning salon" or "I had my nails done at a nail salon".

I haven't heard the term "salon hair". I could see it being used to refer to a type of hair. But no fluent English speaker would use it to refer to a type of salon. Cases where an adjective follows a noun in English are very rare and at that often misunderstood. Confer "court martial".

@Jay So do you think there's actually the phrase "salon hair"? Even so, that's clearly not what OP meant here.

@Jay "court martial" is indeed an interesting case. Even I don't know exactly why it's called that way.

@LukeL that was before internet existed

@jsotola What's invented before internet existed? "Court martial" or "salon hair"? Me and Jay moved on to this other topic, so I'm not exactly sure which one are you referring.

Beautiful hair is a never ending quest. We scoured the list of top salon hair treatments that can restore the body, shine and improve the health of your locks instantly. Here’s our list of the best salon hair treatment services that repair damaged hair.

@LukeL - most sources suggest that the word order of 'court martial' derives from the French cour martiale (means the same thing).

The "salon hair" in this case only valid because it's actually "salon hair treatment". "salon hair" without anything following is still invalid.

Downvoter, please state the reason for downvoting.

@MichaelHarvey OK, thanks for telling me! So "court martial" actually have an origin in french.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

"Court martial" and "consul general" are the only examples I can think of in English where the adjective follows the noun. There may be a few others that I never heard of or that just aren't coming to mind at the moment. But they're certainly very rare.

@michaelharvey Your citation is not about "salon hair", but about "salon hair TREATMENT". That is, it is not a salon of type hair, but a treatment of types hair and salon.

Re court martial: In the armoury where I was assigned while undergoing military training, all the items were listed first by kind and then by type, as in "drum snare, drum tenor, drum bass.

@Jay Yeah, that's what I'm trying to say in one of the above comments. "salon hair treatment" certainly doesn't qualify as proof that "salon hair" is OK.

@Mari-LouA OK, I'll change my edit. But I think you shouldn't have posted it as a comment to my answer to this question, you should just inform me in a comment to the question itself. (What I'm essentially saying is that my edit to the question have nothing to do with my answer; they are not related). To address me, use the at (@) symbol, followed by my user name, "Luke L".

Happy to delete my comments, but I thought you deserved to hear why the suggested was rejected by two experienced users.

@RonaldSole: but nobody would call those drums by those phrases unless they were reading from the inventory, would they? The legal and ceremonial phrases like those quoted by Jay, and also "secretary general", "heir apparent", cannot usually be reversed to the normal English order.

@ColinFine  I was suggesting that the use of post positive adjectives is common in the military - hence court martial. Interestingly, Wikipedia lists dozens of such examples that  are commonly found in law, religious texts, some professions and other circles. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective

@ColinFine Exactly. Yes, inventory lists will sometimes write item descriptions that way. But no one calls them that in ordinary speech. I've never heard anyone say "I played a drum snare in the Army Band."

@RonaldSole Your link is interesting. Some of their examples I would agree fit this pattern, like "chicken supreme" and "heir apparent". A few are unintersting because while the article claims they are English, they are most obviously not. Like "mens rea" is not English. It is a Latin phrase that we use in English. ...

... Most of their examples I think fall into a different category, like "nothing important" and "stars visible". I can't really articulate why those are different, but intuitively I think they are. Like yes, someone might say, "Stars visible during an eclipse are ..." But no one says, "I saw three stars visible last night."

@Jay, When an attributive adjective has a complement (like visible during an eclipse) the normal order in English is for that phrase to be postposed.
